# MSaccess, get unique column from joining two tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table called Parts, PartRefID is the PK (not all rows/columns shown)

```
PartRefID   PartDefID   AssemblyID                               Description
1           2           c63df10b-8250-4aa5-9889-9e8046331dbf     Connector
11          1           db51f4a8-3ffa-41f7-81c1-a9accbbb299a     Connector
67          6           136fc5d8-7b65-41b5-bca3-7d4180a1e0ab     Connector
77          5           38fa8b7a-2945-4546-8eab-7865a1e515b2     Connector
133         2           c63df10b-8250-4aa5-9889-9e8046331dbf     Connector
134         6           136fc5d8-7b65-41b5-bca3-7d4180a1e0ab     Connector
```

And a table called PartDefinitions, PartDefID is the PK  (not all rows/columns shown)

```
PartDefID   PartClass   PartNumber         Description
1           1           MS27467T23F55P     Connector, Circular 55-pin plug
2           1           330-00186-09       Connector, Dsub 9-pin plug
3           2           336-00024-00       Contact, pin MIL crimp, size 20
4           2           336-00022-00       Contact, socket MIL crimp, size 20
5           1           MS27468T23F55S     Connector, Circular 55-pin socket
6           1           330-00184-09       Connector, Dsub 9-pin socket
```

I need to extract rows (with all columns) from the Parts table with a unique AssemblyID and a PartClass of 1 (from the associated partDefinitions table).
with my limited sql knowledge I decided a join was necessary and came up with the following code:

```sql
SELECT Parts.*, PartDefinitions.PartClass 
From PartDefinitions 
INNER Join Parts
  On PartDefinitions.PartDefID = Parts.PartDefID 
Where PartDefinitions.PartClass = 1
```

this gets me close, it produces all the rows in the parts table which have an associated column in the partDefinitions table with a column PartClass = 1. This will look just like the example part table above. However there are some duplicate AssemblyID's (NOT duplicate rows) in the returned data. In the example part table above, the last two rows (which have AssemblyID column values which exist in other rows) should not be included.
what I need is to produce the following:

```
PartRefID   PartDefID   AssemblyID
1           2           c63df10b-8250-4aa5-9889-9e8046331dbf
11          1           db51f4a8-3ffa-41f7-81c1-a9accbbb299a
67          6           136fc5d8-7b65-41b5-bca3-7d4180a1e0ab
77          5           38fa8b7a-2945-4546-8eab-7865a1e515b2
```

Just for clarity:
"parts" table has assemblyID, "partdefinitions" table does not
"partDefinitions" table has PartClass, "parts" table does not
"parts" table has PartRefID and PartDefID
"partDefinitions" table has only PartDefID

my apologies if I have not made a clear and concise question

thanks for any help

Comment: Are they really duplicates if they differ by `PartRefID`? This looks to be a many-to-one merge with `PartDefinitions` resembles a lookup table.

Comment: if I run the code I listed in my question I will get rows with duplicate assemblyID's (I don't want to give an example in this comment because I don't think I can format the table to look right)

Comment: I understand the result of one-to-many joins, but it is not exactly duplicate rows. The lookup table will repeat for every corresponding join since it extends needed info. If you are running a report of `AssemblyId` than avoid selecting all columns with `*` and unique IDs and join/aggregate with a few columns.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to extract rows from the Parts table with a unique AssemblyID and a PartClass of 1

You can add the restriction on the `AssemblyId` using `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT p.*, pd.PartClass 
FROM PartDefinitions as pd INNER JOIN
     Parts as p
     ON pd.PartDefID = p.PartDefID 
WHERE pd.PartClass = 1 AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Parts as p2
                  WHERE p2.AssemblyID = p.AssemblyID AND
                        p2.PartRefID <> p.PartRefID
                 );
```

Comment: that returns no rows at all. shouldn't the SELECT be on the Parts Table and the JOIN on the PartDefinitions table?

Comment: @Perry59 . . . I have no idea what the comment refers to.  The `JOIN` is on both tables and the `SELECT` is taken directly from the question.

Comment: in my question, the partial solution I had began with "SELECT Parts.*" yours looked different so I was confused by it. It (your sql statement) still returns no rows though

Comment: @Perry59 . . . It uses table aliases so the query is easier to write and read -- and also so the correlated subquery works.

Comment: yes, I'm new to "alias's" so they throw me sometimes. Your code will return the same rows as my original, simple sql statement IF I leave off the last line "AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Parts as p2 WHERE p2.AssemblyID = p.AssemblyID AND p2.PartRefID <> p.PartRefID)"  I think the issue there is that only the "parts" table has the column assemblyID, not both tables. also, only the "parts" table has the column PartRefID, not both tables. so the last line of your statement seems to be looking for the same columns in both tables which is not the case.

Comment: @Perry59 . . . I don't follow your comment at all.  The correlated subquery is ensuring that only one part has a given assembly id.

Comment: I really do not know how to make my comment more clear. the sql statement you provided returns NOTHING unless I delete the last line of it "AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Parts as p2 WHERE p2.AssemblyID = p.AssemblyID AND p2.PartRefID <> p.PartRefID)". then it returns the same rows I got with my simple statement in the original question

Comment: in case it's not clear by the above tables: "parts" table has assemblyID, "partdefinitions" table does not
"partDefinitions" table has PartClass, "parts" table does not
"parts" table has PartRefID and PartDefID
"partDefinitions" table has only PartDefID

Comment: @Perry59 . . . I'm lost on your comment.  This query only refers to `AssemblyID` in the `parts` table.  Your question is pretty clear on which table has which columns.

Answer (score 0):

Consider merging on an aggregate query that returns the minimum of `PartsRefID`:

```sql
SELECT agg.MinPartRefID, agg.PartDefID, agg.AssemblyID
     , pd.PartClass, pd.PartNumber, pd.Description
FROM PartDefinitions pd
INNER JOIN
   (SELECT PartDefID, AssemblyID, MIN(PartRefID) AS MinPartsRefID
    FROM Parts
    GROUP BY PartDefID, AssemblyID) As agg
   ON pd.PartDefID = agg.PartDefID 
WHERE pd.PartClass = 1
```

Comment: if I run that code in the query editor it thinks "PartsRefID" is a parameter and asks for a value.

Comment: Whoops. Parameter prompt usually are due to typos. Simply fix it.

Comment: I found the typo and simply fixed it. This now returns the two unique assemblyID columns I need but unfortunately returns row data from the partsdefinition table and not from the parts table

Comment: This solution follows your desired result (*what I need is to produce the following*) with additional columns I thought were pertinent.